# How to launch a desktop application in Ubuntu/Debian on system startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, startup

I've done a hell lot of research, all of which say something like "add your script in init.d" "link symbol in rc*.d", but I still cannot understand without an example. I've tried many times but all failed.

My problem is as simple as:
How to launch `/usr/bin/gedit` on Ubuntu/Debian (desktop version) startup (after user login)?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** So here is what I have done so far:

1) I added a new line `/usr/bin/gedit` before `exit 0` in `/etc/rc.local`, and ran `sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`. However, when I reboot and logged in to the desktop, nothing happened.

2) (Having clear the new line added in `/etc/rc.local`) I created a script `/etc/init.d/gedit`, of which the content is:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        /usr/bin/gedit
        ;;
    stop)
        killall gedit
        ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 5
        $0 start
        ;;
    reload|force-reload)
esac
```

And then I ran `sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/gedit`. Next, I ran `sudo update-rc.d gedit defaults`, which gave me the following output:

```
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/gedit missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScript>
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/gedit ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20gedit -> ../init.d/gedit
   /etc/rc1.d/K20gedit -> ../init.d/gedit
   /etc/rc6.d/K20gedit -> ../init.d/gedit
   /etc/rc2.d/S20gedit -> ../init.d/gedit
   /etc/rc3.d/S20gedit -> ../init.d/gedit
   /etc/rc4.d/S20gedit -> ../init.d/gedit
   /etc/rc5.d/S20gedit -> ../init.d/gedit
```

Then I tried `invoke-rc.d gedit start`, and `gedit` popped up as intended. **However, when I reboot and logged in to the desktop, again nothing happened.**

**P.S.** Setting up in `Startup Applications` of Ubuntu does work, but what I want is actually a more general approach which can be used when distributing my own software package.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add gedit at **System > Preferences > Startup Applications**?

Also look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup

Comment: This works, but is there a more general approach which will work on most, if not all, desktop Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help

[Running a Program at Linux Startup](http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Running_a_Program_at_Linux_Startup)

Comment: Thank you, but after I do as it says nothing happens. Please see my edit.